# How to remove (or disable) pop up "Search | Copy" in Opera?

Tags: browser, opera, user-interface, popups

I need to disable pop up text:
[image: Pop up image (Opera 52)]
that shows after text selection in Opera browser v52.0 (OS Windows).
Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer [here](https://forums.opera.com/topic/17320/disable-search-and-copy-pop-up-menu-after-selection).

> Settings > Browser, in the User interface section. It says "Enable the search pop-up when selecting text" - clear the checkbox and it will go away.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com) over this issue.  It's a fork of Opera and still in Chromium.  This issue does not exist by default and it brought a lot of other features that I enjoy, especially regarding the use of tabs.  My favorite is having tabs on the left-side.